# fill an array with missing values and keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$all_zones` that comes sometimes with missing keys and values and I would like to fill the array with empty values for the messing keys, here's the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 1
            [name] => Europe
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 6.00
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 3
            [name] => Asia
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 4
            [name] => Africa
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 6.00
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 5
            [name] => Oceania
        )
)
```

The thing is the `$all_zones[$key]['price']` depend on how many `ranges` there's for each Zone, inthis case `$range_count = count($all_ranges);` will display `2`, so I'd like to fill the missing keys for `2` times : Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 1
            [name] => Europe
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 6.00
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 3
            [name] => Asia
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 4
            [name] => Africa
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.00
                    [1] => 6.00
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_zone] => 5
            [name] => Oceania
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

            [id_delivery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Here's what I've tried so far and didn't succeed:

```
$range_count = count($all_ranges);
$i=0;
foreach ($all_zones as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value['id_zone']) && isset($value['name']) && (!isset($value['price']) || !isset($value['id_delivery']))){
        if($range_count>$i){
                $disabled[]=$key;
                $all_zones[$key]['price'][] = '';
                $all_zones[$key]['id_delivery'][] = '';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: What is `$all_ranges`? I mean what data does it hold?

Comment: As I said `$all_ranges` will show how many time I sould repeat the process of inserting empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$range_count = count($all_ranges);

foreach ($all_zones as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value['id_zone']) && isset($value['name']) && (!isset($value['price']) || !isset($value['id_delivery']))){

        $disabled[]=$key;
        if((!isset($value['price']))
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$range_count<$i++)
            {
                $all_zones[$key]['id_delivery'][] = '';
            }
        }

        if((!isset($value['id_delivery']))
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$range_count<$i++)
            {
                $all_zones[$key]['id_delivery'][] = '';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to loop through the array, with an [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) on each array within the parent array to set your 'defaults'.

```
$zone_template = array(
    'id_zone' => '',
    'name' => '',
    'price' => array(
        0 => '',
        1 => ''
    ),
    'id_delivery' = array(
        0 => '',
        1 => ''
    )
);

foreach ($all_zones as $zone) {
    array_merge($zone_template, $zone);
}
```

Can also be done with [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 0):

You might have operator precedence problem.

```
(  (!isset($value['price']) || !isset($value['id_delivery']))  )
```